# Iterate over a java List

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I have these entities: `ReleveBancaireEntity` `LigneReleveEntity` `OperationCreditEntity` and these transactions entities `OperationChequeEntity` `OperationVirementEntity` and `OperationEspeceEntity`

- So my `ReleveBancaireEntity` has a list of `LigneReleveEntity` and `OperationCreditEntity` has inheritance of type single table and all transactions entities extends from `OperationCreditEntity`, my goal is to verify and filter `LigneReleveEntity` based on a field called `private String creditDebit;` and see if it has letter `D` I should ignore it and don't persist it, and if it has letter `C` I want to persist it to the database `OperationCreditEntity`
  Here are my entites:

**ReleveBancaireEntity**

```
public class ReleveBancaireEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long releveBancaireId;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateReception;
    private String label;
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "releveBancaire", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<LigneReleveEntity> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**LigneReleveEntity**

```
public class LigneReleveEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long ligneReleveId;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOperation;
    private String operationNature;
    private BigDecimal montant;
    private String creditDebit;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_releveBancaire", referencedColumnName = "releveBancaireId")
    private ReleveBancaireEntity releveBancaire;
}
```

**OperationCreditEntity**

```
public class OperationCreditEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long operationCreditId;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date operationDate;
    @OneToOne
    private LigneReleveEntity ligneReleve;
}
```

**OperationEspecesEntity**

```
@DiscriminatorValue("Operation_Especes")
public class OperationEspecesEntity extends OperationCreditEntity {
    private String cin;
    private String nomEmetteur;
    private String prenomEmetteur;
}
```

**OperationVirementEntity**

```
@DiscriminatorValue("Operation_Virement")
public class OperationVirementEntity extends OperationCreditEntity {
    private String rib;
}
```

**OperationChequeEntity**

```
@DiscriminatorValue("Operation_Cheque")
public class OperationChequeEntity extends OperationCreditEntity{
    private int numeroCheque;
}
```

**This is how OperationCreditEntity Table looks like:**

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
public void qualification(Long releveBancaireId){
    List<LigneReleveEntity> ligneReleveEntities  = new ArrayList<>();
    OperationCreditEntity operationCreditEntity = new OperationCreditEntity();
    LigneReleveEntity ligneReleve = new LigneReleveEntity();
    Predicate<LigneReleveEntity> byCredit = credit -> Objects.equals(credit.getCreditDebit(), "C");
    if (!Objects.equals(ligneReleve.getCreditDebit(), "C")){
        throw new RuntimeException("Ignoring ...");
    }
    ligneReleveEntities.stream().filter(byCredit).collect(Collectors.toList());
    operationCreditRepository.save(operationCreditEntity);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code you've tried?  It seems like all you need is to filter a list?

Comment: Yes when I try to post request my service should check if `creditDebit` has data `C` I should persist to `OperationCredit` table and check whether it be of type `OperationVirementEntity` or `OperationChequeEntity` or `OperationEspecesEntity` because I have inheritance. I tried these lines of code but no results I'll post it next answer.

Comment: I added your code snippet to your question, just to make it easier for everyone to digest.  When this line runs `ligneReleveEntities.stream().filter(byCredit).collect(Collectors.toList());` it produces a new list, which you discard, and then you're saving `operationCreditEntity` which you've instantiated but you don't mutate.change in any way.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I tried :

```
public void qualification(Long releveBancaireId){
        List<LigneReleveEntity> ligneReleveEntities  = new ArrayList<>();
        OperationCreditEntity operationCreditEntity = new OperationCreditEntity();
        LigneReleveEntity ligneReleve = new LigneReleveEntity();
        Predicate<LigneReleveEntity> byCredit = credit -> Objects.equals(credit.getCreditDebit(), "C");
        if (!Objects.equals(ligneReleve.getCreditDebit(), "C")){
            throw new RuntimeException("Ignoring ...");
        }
        ligneReleveEntities.stream().filter(byCredit).collect(Collectors.toList());
        operationCreditRepository.save(operationCreditEntity);
    }
```

Comment: You need to do something with `ligneReleveEntities.`. Right now, you just create an empty list and filter through it.

Comment: but how to filter based on `creditDebit` if it has `C` or `D` and persist it to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public void qualification(Long releveBancaireId){

    ReleveBancaireEntity releveBancaire = ...; // find entity by id
    List<OperationCreditEntity> operationsCredit =  releveBancaire.getLignereleve()
        .stream()
        .filter(ligne -> "C".equals(ligne.getCreditDebit())
        .map(ligne -> /* map to OperationCreditEntity here */)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    operationCreditRepository.save(operationsCredit);
}
```

Comment: Hey Taylor Please can yuo update this line `/* map to OperationCreditEntity here */`

Comment: but that's up to your business logic, how would I know?

Comment: the logic here is just to get list from database, then filter each line that has `C`, then save that filtred list to database that's it I tried everything and nothing works

Comment: where do you want to save the list?  What's with all the OperationCreditEntity objects you posted above?  how are those relevant?